# I need to change package name in AdMob

Tags: admob

My app is published on the play store and it already implements AdMob, in my AdMob app's settings the package name is wrong so now I can't link it to the play store.

How can I change the package name on AdMob?

do I have to create a new app, create a new banner, modify the app and republish it on the playstore?

Comment: I too need to change the package name if someone can help please

Comment: Any update on this?